# Ansible 1.6 include with_items deprecated

Tags: deprecated, ansible

So looks like this feature has been deprecated, i really don't understand why, Ansible CTO's says that we should use instead with_nested but honestly i have no idea how to do it,

Here's my playboook:

```
- hosts: all
  user: root
  vars: 
   - sites:
     - site: site1.com
       repo: ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/orgname/reponame
       nginx_ssl: true;
       copy_init:
        - path1/file1.txt
        - path2/file2.php
        - path2/file3.php

     - site: site2.net
       repo: ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/orgname/reposite2

     - site: site4.com
       repo: ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/orgname/reposite3
       copy_init:
        - path2/file2.php

  tasks:
     - name: Bootstrap Sites
      include: bootstrap_site.yml site={{item}}
```

And the error message when trying to execute this in Ansible 1.6.6:

> ERROR: [DEPRECATED]: include + with_items is a removed deprecated feature.  Please update your playbooks.

How can i convert this playbook to something that works with this ansible version?

Comment: I'm missing something. Where's the `with_items`. Where's the `item` coming from?

Answer (score 21):

There's no drop-in replacement, unfortunately. Some things you can do:

- Pass the list to your included file and iterate there. In your playbook:

  ```
  vars:
      sites:
         - site1
         - site2
  tasks:
      - include: bootstrap_site.yml sites={{sites}}
  ```

  And in bootstrap_site.yml:

  ```
  - some_Task: ...
    with_items: sites

  - another_task: ...
    with_items: sites

  ...
  ```
- Rewrite bootstrap_site as a [module](http://docs.ansible.com/developing_modules.html) (in python, bash, whatever), put it in a `library` dir next to your playbook. Then you could do:

  ```
  - bootstrap_site: site={{item}}
    with_items: sites
  ```

**Update:** Ansible V2 is out and brings back the include + with_items [combo loop](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#loops-and-includes-in-2-0)!

Comment: Thanks, actually i already tried going on with first solution you prupose but its too cumbersome, as there's tasks that already loop through subitems, and getting nested loops its overcomplicated, i would love going for the second solution though! looks great, but.. can't i do it in ansible itself?  and.. btw, any insight of why this have been deprecated?

Comment: It's been deprecated because [supposedly](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/3512#issuecomment-20873812) people used it mainly with inventory variables, and for implementation reasons they can't be used like that. So to avoid confusion (why some variables work while others don't) they just removed the feature. Is using with_nested not practical in your case? Regarding writing modules in YAML, no can do, I'm afraid.

Comment: okay thanks, its quite frustrating as seems a really simple feature to have, given the amount of things you can do with ansible, this looks like trivial one, but i guess thats because i don't fully understand what is going under the hood.  with_nested is much more complicated to use for 3 or 4 level subarrays, so i finally went with another solution, doing 1 include task per each array item, is not the cleanest but works...

Comment: Thanks for the update. Good to see it is coming back. Removing a feature that so many people used was a big mistake in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to circumvent the blahblah-deprecated message... as asked in the original post.

I added a file vars/filenames.yml:

```
  filenames:
  - file1
  - file2
  - file3
```

Next I read these names at the beginning of the playbook:

```
  - name: read filenames
    include_vars: vars/filenames.yml
```

Then, I can use them later:

```
  - name: Copy files 1
    copy: src=/filesrc1/{{ item }} dest=/filedest1/{{ item }} owner=me group=we
    with_items: filenames
```

and so on....

Regards,
Tom